# SLURM/OpenMPI/R/Rmpi/OpenMP issue

Tags: r, openmp, openmpi, slurm, cgroups

My issue is that when I spawn 2 Rslaves, my OpenMP process seems to be pinned to a core.  When I spawn 3 slaves in SAME job (when my job config allows), I can span the assigned cores.

Here is what I am doing:

launch job on cluster, for instance an interactive (sbatch gives similar results) job using 3 nodes, 3 tasks per node (so I can experiment), and 4 cores per task:

`salloc -A arctest --gres=gpu:1  --partition=v100_dev_q -N 3 --tasks-per-node=2 --cpus-per-task=4 --time=2:00:00 srun -n1 -N1 --pty --preserve-env --cpu-bind=no --mpi=pmi2 --distribution=cycl
ic:cyclic $SHELL`

load some software:

`module load intel/18.2 R/3.6.1 openmpi/4.0.1 R-parallel/3.6.1 cuda/10.1.168`
We are using SLURM 17.11 (I think) with cgroups enabled, UCX 1.3.0, ofed 4.2.1.2
OpenMPI was compiled using:

```
              --with-cma \
            --enable-dlopen \
            --enable-shared \
            --with-mxm=/opt/mellanox/mxm \
            --with-pmi=/usr \
            --with-slurm
```

and all of this is on Mellanox ConnectX-5 cards.

```
cgroups.conf
CgroupAutomount=yes
ConstrainCores=yes
ConstrainDevices=yes
ConstrainRAMSpace=yes
ConstrainSwapSpace=yes
AllowedSwapSpace=4
```

Run a quick OpenMP on the master node to see I am not confined to a single core:
`./openmp_example`

```
openmp_example.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(10)
  {
    char hostbuffer[256];
    int hostname;
    hostname = gethostname(hostbuffer, sizeof(hostbuffer));
    int schedaff = sched_getaffinity();
    int coreid = sched_getcpu();
    int id = omp_get_thread_num();
    int total = omp_get_num_threads();
    int maxthread = omp_get_max_threads();
    //printf("host %s\n", hostbuffer);
    printf("Host: %s : core: %d , I am running process %d out of %d (max %d ) with affinity %d \n", hostbuffer, coreid, id, total, maxthread, schedaff);
  }
  printf("parallel for ends.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Getting output similar to:

```
Host: ca223 : core: 0 , I am running process 8 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 8 , I am running process 7 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 2 , I am running process 9 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 6 , I am running process 3 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 8 , I am running process 2 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 10 , I am running process 1 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 4 , I am running process 4 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 12 , I am running process 6 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 14 , I am running process 5 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 18 , I am running process 0 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
```

Looks good, so lets add some R/Rmpi after making a host file

```
hostfile
ca223 slots=2
ca224 slots=2
```

First, lets do this with 2 slaves:

```
mpirun -v -np 1 --bind-to none --hostfile hostfile --mca mpi_warn_on_fork 0 --mca btl_openib_allow_ib 1 Rscript omp_test_S2.R
```

with this

```
omp_test_S2.R
library("Rmpi")

#
# In case R exits unexpectedly, have it automatically clean up
# resources taken up by Rmpi (slaves, memory, etc...)
.Last <- function(){
       if (is.loaded("mpi_initialize")){
           if (mpi.comm.size(1) > 0){
               print("Please use mpi.close.Rslaves() to close slaves.")
               mpi.close.Rslaves()
           }
           print("Please use mpi.quit() to quit R")
           .Call("mpi_finalize")
       }
}

Sys.setenv(OMP_NUM_THREADS = 12 )
Sys.setenv(OMP_PROC_BIND = "false")

cat("show quick core spread on master","\n",sep="")
system("./openmp_example")

ns <- mpi.universe.size()
cat("mpi.universe.size = ",ns,"\n",sep="")
ns <- 2
mpi.spawn.Rslaves(nslaves=ns)

# Tell all slaves to return a message identifying themselves
mpi.bcast.cmd( id <- mpi.comm.rank() )
mpi.bcast.cmd( ns <- mpi.comm.size() )
mpi.bcast.cmd( host <- mpi.get.processor.name() )
mpi.bcast.cmd( Sys.setenv(OMP_NUM_THREADS = 12 ))
mpi.bcast.cmd( Sys.setenv(OMP_PROC_BIND = "false") )
mpi.remote.exec(paste("I am",mpi.comm.rank(),"of",mpi.comm.size()))

mpi.bcast.cmd(system('./openmp_example >>slave_S2'))
mpi.bcast.cmd(system('env >> slave_env_S2'))

##system("./openmp_example")

# Tell all slaves to close down, and exit the program
mpi.close.Rslaves(dellog = FALSE)
mpi.quit()
```

Which gives output similar to following:

```
core spread from slaves
Host: ca223 : core: 4 , I am running process 0 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 4 , I am running process 2 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 4 , I am running process 3 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 4 , I am running process 4 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 4 , I am running process 5 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 4 , I am running process 6 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 4 , I am running process 7 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 4 , I am running process 8 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 4 , I am running process 9 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 4 , I am running process 1 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
parallel for ends.
Host: ca224 : core: 0 , I am running process 0 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 0 , I am running process 2 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 0 , I am running process 3 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 0 , I am running process 4 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 0 , I am running process 5 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 0 , I am running process 6 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 0 , I am running process 7 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 0 , I am running process 8 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 0 , I am running process 9 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 0 , I am running process 1 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
parallel for ends.
```

OK, so stuck to core 4 and core 0 on the slaves.  Let's try 3 slaves, same mpi call, but using a R script with slaves set to 3 and look at output:

```
core spread from slaves
Host: ca223 : core: 2 , I am running process 9 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 8 , I am running process 7 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 18 , I am running process 0 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 0 , I am running process 8 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 6 , I am running process 3 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 10 , I am running process 1 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 12 , I am running process 6 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 4 , I am running process 4 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 8 , I am running process 2 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca223 : core: 14 , I am running process 5 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
parallel for ends.
Host: ca224 : core: 2 , I am running process 8 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 16 , I am running process 5 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 10 , I am running process 1 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 0 , I am running process 9 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 6 , I am running process 2 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 4 , I am running process 3 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 12 , I am running process 4 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 10 , I am running process 7 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 14 , I am running process 6 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 18 , I am running process 0 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
parallel for ends.
Host: ca224 : core: 8 , I am running process 0 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 16 , I am running process 7 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 2 , I am running process 3 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 6 , I am running process 2 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 14 , I am running process 8 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 8 , I am running process 1 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 16 , I am running process 5 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 16 , I am running process 9 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 16 , I am running process 6 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca224 : core: 16 , I am running process 4 out of 10 (max 12 ) with affinity -1
parallel for ends.
```

So what is the deal with 2 slaves?

Few things:

1. OpenMPI 3 (hostfile part is broken when using -map-by so can't lay out the slaves)
2. OpenMPI 4.0.2 similar results
3. GCC/OpenMPI
4. Different cluster, same versions of SLURM/R/etc
5. OpenMPI 1.10.7 -- ran into issue where my bcast+system call simply doesn't spit out to file
6. Tried compiling OpenMPI --without-slurm, get `Run failed due to: pml_ucx.c:176 Error: Failed to receive UCX worker address` and have not tried to turn off UCX to use ob1.  Well, gave it a quick go but could try harder.

   7. `--exlusive` flag doesn't change behavior
   8. salloc vs script and sbatch same behavior
   9. Need to try a non-SLURM cluster.  Perhaps with some eggnog ...

Has anyone else seen this? I am not quite sure where to look for the problem. It seems to me that it all works in the 3 slave case, so R and Rmpi are in the clear, is this a SLURM-OpenMPI problem? Is there an environmental variable I need to look at?

While asking the question, mpi.universe.size() now seems to match the configuration from slurm, ie nodes=2, tasks=3 gives a size of 6.  What if I want that to simply be the same as the count of nodes? Ideally this would be something I would get from an mpi call and not a slurm env.

As a follow up, I can see `--bind-to` is working for `-np 2`:

```
mpirun -np 2 --bind-to none --hostfile hostfile --map-by ppr:1:node --mca mpi_warn_on_fork 0 --mca btl_openib_allow_ib 1 ./openmp_example
Host: ca207 : core: 2 , I am running process 8 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 0 , I am running process 9 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 14 , I am running process 0 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 8 , I am running process 2 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 6 , I am running process 3 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 4 , I am running process 4 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 10 , I am running process 1 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 12 , I am running process 6 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 0 , I am running process 5 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 8 , I am running process 7 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
parallel for ends.
Host: ca208 : core: 2 , I am running process 9 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 0 , I am running process 8 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 14 , I am running process 0 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 6 , I am running process 3 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 10 , I am running process 1 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 4 , I am running process 4 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 12 , I am running process 6 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 2 , I am running process 5 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 8 , I am running process 2 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 8 , I am running process 7 out of 10 (max 8 ) with affinity -1
parallel for ends.

mpirun -np 2 --hostfile hostfile --map-by ppr:1:node --mca mpi_warn_on_fork 0 --mca btl_openib_allow_ib 1 ./openmp_example
Host: ca207 : core: 0 , I am running process 0 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 0 , I am running process 1 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 0 , I am running process 0 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 0 , I am running process 2 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 0 , I am running process 4 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 0 , I am running process 8 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 0 , I am running process 2 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 0 , I am running process 3 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 0 , I am running process 9 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 0 , I am running process 5 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 0 , I am running process 7 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca207 : core: 0 , I am running process 6 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
parallel for ends.
Host: ca208 : core: 0 , I am running process 3 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 0 , I am running process 4 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 0 , I am running process 5 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 0 , I am running process 6 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 0 , I am running process 7 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 0 , I am running process 8 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 0 , I am running process 9 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
Host: ca208 : core: 0 , I am running process 1 out of 10 (max 1 ) with affinity -1
```

Comment: It seems to me (although I fail to find this information back) that OpenMPI has binding to core enabled by default when launching up to 2 processes and disabled by default when launching more than 2... This might be wrong and just me mixing-up with something else, but maybe this a lead...

Comment: Yes, I was thinking same.  For the mpirun -np 2 ./openmp_example, I can show that the --bind-to none flag is working, it is when I have Rmpi launch it that it fails to carry through is my guess, but I am not sure how to check that through a look at the env on the slave side.  This is why I put a mpi.bcast command to set the OMP_PROC_BIND = "false" on the slave side as a just in case.  I can see that env variable is set, so that is good.  But truthfully, without it, I get the same behavior.

Comment: I think somehow it is the sub process that isn't getting the binding information or somehow isn't seeing the full cpuset.  And btw, you are correct as per the docs:  `Bind to core:
    when the number of processes is <= 2 
Bind to socket:
    when the number of processes is > 2 
Bind to none:
    when oversubscribed`. I have tried using the `--oversubscribe` flag, but when using that I can't find a way to layout the slaves as 1 per node.

Comment: After this hint, I realized I should run more threads in my openmp_example to see if it is stuck to a socket as per the mpirun default for greater than 2 processes.  Indeed it is fully uncontained when run directly using mpirun --bind-to none, but it stuck to a socket when launched via an Rslave.

Comment: OK, resolved.  The issue we were running against is that the default for mpirun is now to not pass bindings to sub processes.  The fix (as per Ralph -- <https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/7295#issuecomment-573090694> ) is to change rmaps_base_inherit

Comment: "OMPI changed its default behavior in v4.0 such that child jobs no longer automatically "inherit" the map/bind directives of their parents. Lots of reasons why this was done. In this case, you probably do want the children to inherit the directives, so you need to set the "rmaps_base_inherit" MCA parameter (either on the mpirun cmd line or in the environment). Any non-zero value is fine as it is a boolean parameter."